# Should Linguistics participate in Winter Bash 2014?

Tags: discussion

Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can “wear”.

This event will run from **15 December 2014** to **4 January 2015**. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on winterbash2014.stackexchange.com. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, **at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage**.

The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

**Please indicate your preference by up-voting your preferred answer below.** Since the mods have to respond by 1 December 2014, the Linguistics mods will wait for your vote until the end of **29 November 2014**. We, mods, will reserve 30 November as a buffer for timezone differences and other eventualities.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, Linguistics should participate in Winter Bash 2014.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, Linguistics should **not** participate in Winter Bash 2014.